# Lubunu 16.10 doesn't install nvidia-304 in kernel

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have used nvidia-304 successfully with Lubuntu up through 16.04.
(With nouveau, at some time or other, the screen "crashes" and I have to hard-shutdown)

This time, with 16.10, I first noticed only 3 screen resolutions possible - max being 1024x768.
Further research showed:

```
Monitor Settings:  
"The following monitor is detected...
Default Monitor"

scott@scott-ASUS-M2N68-AM-PLUS:~$ sudo lshw -c video
[sudo] password for scott: 
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: C61 [GeForce 7025 / nForce 630a]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: d
       bus info: pci@0000:00:0d.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:dd000000-ddffffff memory:c0000-dffff

scott@scott-ASUS-M2N68-AM-PLUS:~$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      61.00* 
   800x600       61.00  
   640x480       60.00
```

The install from Synaptic had appeared to go just fine:

```
Gtk-WARNING **: Theme directory  imported-Humanity/192 of theme Lubuntu has no size field
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-304.
(Reading database ... 171834 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-nvidia-304_304.132-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-304 (304.132-0ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-current.
Preparing to unpack .../1-nvidia-current_304.132-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-current (304.132-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up nvidia-304 (304.132-0ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-304/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-304/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/share/nvidia-304/glamor.conf to provide /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/glamoregl.conf (glamor_conf) in auto mode
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia-304
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
Loading new nvidia-304-304.132 DKMS files...
Building only for 4.8.0-26-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.8.0-26-generic
Done.

nvidia_304:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.8.0-26-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod.......

DKMS: install completed.
Setting up nvidia-current (304.132-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.125ubuntu5) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-26-generic
```

However, running lsmod showed no nvidia-304 module, nor did it show one for nouveau.  So it had correctly removed nouveau, but did not add nvidia-304.

Un-installing nvidia-304 gets me nouveau in lsmod, it finds the VGA monitor for xrandr and Monitor Settings, lshw just shows "*-display", and I can use up to 1600x1200 - but sooner or later I have to do a hard-shutdown...

I just tried using "Additional Drivers" to switch to nvidia-304, but with exactly the same result.
Before I removed the package, I looked through the system logs, and copied out that which looked relevant.

What seemed most important were:
"nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel"
"(EE) NVIDIA: Failed to load the NVIDIA kernel module."
"(EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module-specific error, 0)"

```
dpkg log  (shows install of nvidia-304)

2016-10-24 14:38:21 startup archives unpack
2016-10-24 14:38:23 install nvidia-304:amd64 <none> 304.132-0ubuntu1
2016-10-24 14:38:23 status triggers-pending libc-bin:amd64 2.24-3ubuntu1
2016-10-24 14:38:23 status half-installed nvidia-304:amd64 304.132-0ubuntu1
2016-10-24 14:38:31 status triggers-pending man-db:amd64 2.7.5-1
2016-10-24 14:38:31 status unpacked nvidia-304:amd64 304.132-0ubuntu1
2016-10-24 14:38:31 status unpacked nvidia-304:amd64 304.132-0ubuntu1
2016-10-24 14:38:32 startup packages configure
2016-10-24 14:38:32 trigproc libc-bin:amd64 2.24-3ubuntu1 <none>
2016-10-24 14:38:32 status half-configured libc-bin:amd64 2.24-3ubuntu1
2016-10-24 14:38:32 status installed libc-bin:amd64 2.24-3ubuntu1
2016-10-24 14:38:32 trigproc man-db:amd64 2.7.5-1 <none>
2016-10-24 14:38:32 status half-configured man-db:amd64 2.7.5-1
2016-10-24 14:38:33 status installed man-db:amd64 2.7.5-1
2016-10-24 14:38:33 configure nvidia-304:amd64 304.132-0ubuntu1 <none>
2016-10-24 14:38:33 status triggers-pending libc-bin:amd64 2.24-3ubuntu1
2016-10-24 14:38:33 status unpacked nvidia-304:amd64 304.132-0ubuntu1
2016-10-24 14:38:33 status unpacked nvidia-304:amd64 304.132-0ubuntu1
2016-10-24 14:38:33 status half-configured nvidia-304:amd64 304.132-0ubuntu1
2016-10-24 14:39:24 status installed nvidia-304:amd64 304.132-0ubuntu1
2016-10-24 14:39:24 status triggers-pending initramfs-tools:all 0.125ubuntu5
2016-10-24 14:39:24 trigproc libc-bin:amd64 2.24-3ubuntu1 <none>
2016-10-24 14:39:24 status half-configured libc-bin:amd64 2.24-3ubuntu1
2016-10-24 14:39:24 status installed libc-bin:amd64 2.24-3ubuntu1
2016-10-24 14:39:24 trigproc initramfs-tools:all 0.125ubuntu5 <none>
2016-10-24 14:39:24 status half-configured initramfs-tools:all 0.125ubuntu5
2016-10-24 14:39:41 status installed initramfs-tools:all 0.125ubuntu5

syslog  (shows install of nvidia-304, and references to nvidia )

Oct 24 14:38:09 scott-ASUS-M2N68-AM-PLUS AptDaemon: INFO: Initializing daemon
Oct 24 14:38:09 scott-ASUS-M2N68-AM-PLUS org.debian.apt    [667]: 14:38:09 AptDaemon     [INFO]: Initializing daemon
Oct 24 14:38:09 scott-ASUS-M2N68-AM-PLUS dbus    [667]:     [system] Successfully activated service 'org.debian.apt'
Oct 24 14:38:09 scott-ASUS-M2N68-AM-PLUS AptDaemon: INFO: CommitPackages() was called: dbus.Array(    [dbus.String('nivida-304')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array(    [dbus.String('')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array(    [dbus.String('')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array(    [dbus.String('')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array(    [dbus.String('')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array(    [dbus.String('')], signature=dbus.Signature('s'))
Oct 24 14:38:09 scott-ASUS-M2N68-AM-PLUS org.debian.apt    [667]: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker/pkworker.py:35: PyGIWarning: PackageKitGlib was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('PackageKitGlib', '1.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
Oct 24 14:38:09 scott-ASUS-M2N68-AM-PLUS org.debian.apt    [667]:   from gi.repository import PackageKitGlib as pk
Oct 24 14:38:09 scott-ASUS-M2N68-AM-PLUS org.debian.apt    [667]: 14:38:09 AptDaemon     [INFO]: CommitPackages() was called: dbus.Array(    [dbus.String('nvidia-304')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array(    [dbus.String('')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array(    [dbus.String('')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array(    [dbus.String('')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array(    [dbus.String('')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array(    [dbus.String('')], signature=dbus.Signature('s'))
Oct 24 14:38:09 scott-ASUS-M2N68-AM-PLUS AptDaemon.Trans: INFO: Queuing transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/11ebbf46ce2d41a9898ff50c480c6c4e
Oct 24 14:38:09 scott-ASUS-M2N68-AM-PLUS org.debian.apt    [667]: 14:38:09 AptDaemon.Trans     [INFO]: Queuing transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/11ebbf46ce2d41a9898ff50c480c6c4e
Oct 24 14:38:09 scott-ASUS-M2N68-AM-PLUS AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Simulating trans: /org/debian/apt/transaction/11ebbf46ce2d41a9898ff50c480c6c4e
Oct 24 14:38:09 scott-ASUS-M2N68-AM-PLUS org.debian.apt    [667]: 14:38:09 AptDaemon.Worker     [INFO]: Simulating trans: /org/debian/apt/transaction/11ebbf46ce2d41a9898ff50c480c6c4e
Oct 24 14:38:10 scott-ASUS-M2N68-AM-PLUS AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Committing packages: dbus.Array(    [dbus.String('nvidia-304')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array(    [], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array(    [], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array(    [], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array(    [], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array(    [], signature=dbus.Signature('s'))
Oct 24 14:38:10 scott-ASUS-M2N68-AM-PLUS org.debian.apt    [667]: 14:38:10 AptDaemon.Worker     [INFO]: Committing packages: dbus.Array(    [dbus.String('nvidia-304')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array(    [], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array(    [], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array(    [], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array(    [], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array(    [], signature=dbus.Signature('s'))
Oct 24 14:38:19 scott-ASUS-M2N68-AM-PLUS AptDaemon.Worker: INFO: Processing transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/11ebbf46ce2d41a9898ff50c480c6c4e
Oct 24 14:38:19 scott-ASUS-M2N68-AM-PLUS org.debian.apt    [667]: 14:38:19 AptDaemon.Worker     [INFO]: Processing transaction /org/debian/apt/transaction/11ebbf46ce2d41a9898ff50c480c6c4e

Oct 24 14:42:57 scott-ASUS-M2N68-AM-PLUS kernel:     [    0.847569] pci 0000:00:0d.0: Video device with shadowed ROM at     [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff]

Oct 24 14:42:57 scott-ASUS-M2N68-AM-PLUS kernel:     [   10.462239] Linux video capture interface: v2.00

Oct 24 14:42:57 scott-ASUS-M2N68-AM-PLUS kernel:     [   14.079863] input: HDA NVidia Front Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:05.0/sound/card0/input6
Oct 24 14:42:57 scott-ASUS-M2N68-AM-PLUS kernel:     [   14.079923] input: HDA NVidia Rear Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:05.0/sound/card0/input7
Oct 24 14:42:57 scott-ASUS-M2N68-AM-PLUS kernel:     [   14.079973] input: HDA NVidia Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:05.0/sound/card0/input8
Oct 24 14:42:57 scott-ASUS-M2N68-AM-PLUS kernel:     [   14.080023] input: HDA NVidia Line Out as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:05.0/sound/card0/input9
Oct 24 14:42:57 scott-ASUS-M2N68-AM-PLUS kernel:     [   14.080075] input: HDA NVidia Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:05.0/sound/card0/input10
Oct 24 14:42:57 scott-ASUS-M2N68-AM-PLUS kernel:     [   15.086387] nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
Oct 24 14:42:57 scott-ASUS-M2N68-AM-PLUS kernel:     [   15.086393] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
Oct 24 14:42:57 scott-ASUS-M2N68-AM-PLUS kernel:     [   15.086394] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
Oct 24 14:42:57 scott-ASUS-M2N68-AM-PLUS kernel:     [   15.095375] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
Oct 24 14:42:57 scott-ASUS-M2N68-AM-PLUS kernel:     [   15.095631] nvidia: Unknown symbol mtrr_del (err 0)
Oct 24 14:42:57 scott-ASUS-M2N68-AM-PLUS kernel:     [   15.095779] nvidia: Unknown symbol mtrr_add (err 0)

Oct 24 14:43:03 scott-ASUS-M2N68-AM-PLUS kernel:     [   26.579044] nvidia: Unknown symbol mtrr_del (err 0)
Oct 24 14:43:03 scott-ASUS-M2N68-AM-PLUS kernel:     [   26.579194] nvidia: Unknown symbol mtrr_add (err 0)
Oct 24 14:43:03 scott-ASUS-M2N68-AM-PLUS kernel:     [   26.665936] nvidia: Unknown symbol mtrr_del (err 0)
Oct 24 14:43:03 scott-ASUS-M2N68-AM-PLUS kernel:     [   26.666086] nvidia: Unknown symbol mtrr_add (err 0)

X.Org log (references to screen/monitor/nvidia/nouveau)

X.Org X Server 1.18.4
Release Date:     2016-07-19
[    25.566] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.

[    25.760] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    25.760] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    25.760] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    25.760] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    25.761] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.

[    25.764] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    25.785] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglx.so
[    26.362] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    26.362]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    26.362]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    26.362] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  304.132  Fri Sep 16 11:22:36 PDT 2016
[    26.362] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[    26.362] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 1
[    26.362] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
[    26.362] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[    26.362] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
[    26.362] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    26.362] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    26.362] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[    26.430] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    26.430]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    26.430]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    26.485] (EE) NVIDIA: Failed to load the NVIDIA kernel module. Please check your
[    26.485] (EE) NVIDIA:     system's kernel log for additional error messages.
[    26.485] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[    26.485] (II) Unloading nvidia
[    26.485] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module-specific error, 0)
[    26.485] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[    26.495] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[    26.524] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    26.524]    compiled for 1.18.3, module version = 1.0.12
[    26.524]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    26.524]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    26.524] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    26.524] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    26.525] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    26.525]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 1.18.4
[    26.525]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    26.525]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    26.525] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    26.525] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    26.537] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    26.537]    compiled for 1.18.1, module version = 0.4.4
[    26.537]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    26.537]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    26.537] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    26.537] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    26.538] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    26.538]    compiled for 1.18.1, module version = 2.3.4
[    26.538]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    26.538]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    26.538] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[    26.538] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 1
[    26.538] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
[    26.538] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[    26.538] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
[    26.538] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    26.538] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    26.538] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[    26.538] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    26.538]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    26.538]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    26.572] (EE) NVIDIA: Failed to load the NVIDIA kernel module. Please check your
[    26.572] (EE) NVIDIA:     system's kernel log for additional error messages.
[    26.572] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[    26.573] (II) Unloading nvidia
[    26.573] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module-specific error, 0)
[    26.573] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[    26.573] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[    26.573] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    26.573]    compiled for 1.18.3, module version = 1.0.12
[    26.573]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    26.573]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    26.573] (II) UnloadModule: "nouveau"
[    26.573] (II) Unloading nouveau
[    26.573] (II) Failed to load module "nouveau" (already loaded, 0)

[    26.573] (II) NOUVEAU driver Date:   Tue Dec 8 15:52:25 2015 +1000
[    26.573] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[    26.573]    RIVA TNT        (NV04)
[    26.573]    RIVA TNT2       (NV05)
[    26.573]    GeForce 256     (NV10)
[    26.573]    GeForce 2       (NV11, NV15)
[    26.573]    GeForce 4MX     (NV17, NV18)
[    26.573]    GeForce 3       (NV20)
[    26.573]    GeForce 4Ti     (NV25, NV28)
[    26.573]    GeForce FX      (NV3x)
[    26.573]    GeForce 6       (NV4x)
[    26.574]    GeForce 7       (G7x)
[    26.574]    GeForce 8       (G8x)
[    26.574]    GeForce GTX 200 (NVA0)
[    26.574]    GeForce GTX 400 (NVC0)

[    26.960] (II) VESA(0): Primary V_BIOS segment is: 0xc000
[    26.969] (II) VESA(0): VESA BIOS detected
[    26.969] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE Version 3.0
[    26.969] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE Total Mem: 262144 kB
[    26.969] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM: NVIDIA
[    26.969] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Software Rev: 5.97
[    26.969] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
[    26.969] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Product: MCP61 - mcp61-86
[    26.969] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Product Rev: Chip Rev   
[    27.016] (II) VESA(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    27.016] (==) VESA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    27.016] (==) VESA(0): RGB weight 888
[    27.016] (==) VESA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    27.016] (==) VESA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    27.016] (II) Loading sub module "ddc"
[    27.016] (II) LoadModule: "ddc"
[    27.016] (II) Module "ddc" already built-in
[    27.048] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE DDC supported
[    27.048] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE DDC Level none
[    27.048] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE DDC transfer in appr. 0 sec.
[    27.062] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE DDC read failed
[    27.063] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE PanelID read successfully
[    27.063] (II) VESA(0): PanelID returned panel resolution -28952x-32598
[    27.063] (II) VESA(0): ...which I refuse to believe
[    27.063] (II) VESA(0): Searching for matching VESA mode(s):

(here follow many Mode sections)

[    27.108] (II) VESA(0): Total Memory: 4096 64KB banks (262144kB)
[    27.108] (II) VESA(0): <default monitor>: Using default hsync range of 31.50-48.00 kHz
[    27.108] (II) VESA(0): <default monitor>: Using default vrefresh range of 50.00-70.00 Hz
[    27.108] (II) VESA(0): <default monitor>: Using default maximum pixel clock of 65.00 MHz
[    27.108] (WW) VESA(0): Unable to estimate virtual size
[    27.108] (II) VESA(0): Not using built-in mode "2048x1536" (no mode of this name)
[    27.108] (II) VESA(0): Not using built-in mode "1280x1024" (no mode of this name)
[    27.108] (II) VESA(0): Not using built-in mode "1024x768" (no mode of this name)
[    27.108] (II) VESA(0): Not using built-in mode "800x600" (no mode of this name)
[    27.108] (II) VESA(0): Not using built-in mode "640x480" (no mode of this name)
[    27.108] (II) VESA(0): Not using built-in mode "640x400" (no mode of this name)
[    27.108] (II) VESA(0): Not using built-in mode "320x400" (no mode of this name)
[    27.108] (II) VESA(0): Not using built-in mode "320x240" (no mode of this name)
[    27.108] (II) VESA(0): Not using built-in mode "320x200" (no mode of this name)
[    27.108] (WW) VESA(0): No valid modes left. Trying less strict filter...
[    27.108] (II) VESA(0): <default monitor>: Using hsync range of 31.50-48.00 kHz
[    27.108] (II) VESA(0): <default monitor>: Using vrefresh range of 50.00-70.00 Hz
[    27.108] (II) VESA(0): <default monitor>: Using maximum pixel clock of 65.00 MHz
[    27.108] (WW) VESA(0): Unable to estimate virtual size
[    27.118] (II) VESA(0): Not using built-in mode "2048x1536" (hsync out of range)
[    27.118] (II) VESA(0): Not using built-in mode "1280x1024" (hsync out of range)
[    27.118] (II) VESA(0): Not using built-in mode "640x400" (hsync out of range)
[    27.118] (II) VESA(0): Not using built-in mode "320x400" (hsync out of range)
[    27.118] (II) VESA(0): Not using built-in mode "320x240" (illegal horizontal timings)
[    27.118] (II) VESA(0): Not using built-in mode "320x200" (illegal horizontal timings)
[    27.118] (--) VESA(0): Virtual size is 1024x768 (pitch 1024)
[    27.118] (**) VESA(0): *Built-in mode "1024x768"
[    27.118] (**) VESA(0): *Built-in mode "800x600"
[    27.118] (**) VESA(0): *Built-in mode "640x480"
[    27.118] (==) VESA(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[    27.118] (II) VESA(0): Attempting to use 60Hz refresh for mode "1024x768" (118)
[    27.120] (II) VESA(0): Attempting to use 60Hz refresh for mode "800x600" (115)
[    27.121] (II) VESA(0): Attempting to use 60Hz refresh for mode "640x480" (112)

[    27.140] (II) VESA(0): initializing int10
[    27.145] (II) VESA(0): Primary V_BIOS segment is: 0xc000
[    27.153] (II) VESA(0): VESA BIOS detected
[    27.153] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE Version 3.0
[    27.153] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE Total Mem: 262144 kB
[    27.153] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM: NVIDIA
[    27.153] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Software Rev: 5.97
[    27.153] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
[    27.153] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Product: MCP61 - mcp61-86
[    27.153] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Product Rev: Chip Rev   
[    27.154] (II) VESA(0): virtual address = 0x7fbfa0fb0000,
physical address = 0xc0000000, size = 268435456
[    27.181] (II) VESA(0): Setting up VESA Mode 0x118 (1024x768)
[    27.239] (==) VESA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    27.246] (==) VESA(0): Backing store enabled
[    27.247] (==) VESA(0): DPMS enabled
[    27.248] (==) RandR enabled

[    27.259] (EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)
```

Can anyone say why nvidia-304 appears to install, but never makes it into the kernel, and how I can fix this situation?

Also, I assume there is a bug here - for which package should I report it - nvidia-304 (for containing something that causes it not to be installed in the kernal ?) or some other package (that for some reason causes a perfectly-good-nvidia-304 package not to be installed in the kernal ?)

I'm grasping at straws here - I actually considered booting from my 16.04 Lubuntu install to try and grab its nvidia-304 package, but since I have for the first time installed 16.10 as a 64-bit OS, I don't suppose the 32-bit pkg. I come up with would be compatible with it...

Answer (score 0):

This is because of this [Bug reported on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-304/+bug/1634802) ;

A patched version that loads is available in the next version, Ubuntu Zesty, which you can download and install manually.

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-304

This kernel module loaded but did not fix the next problem (a GLX error when loading Unity) ... I ended up removing the nvidia-304 package and falling back to nouveau, which happily seems to be usable in Yakkety.

Comment: The fixed version 304.132-0ubuntu2 does load into the kernel, but the panorama-stitching program Hugin crashes upon starting up (Hugin started fine under Nouveau, but Nouveau itself crashed when attempting to load the photos to stitch). I finally ended up installing the previous version 304.131-0ubuntu5 . This loads into the kernel, and Hugin works fine.